# Cocoa Mac Sheet Rounded Corners (Like Xcode 4)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Does anyone know how you can make a cocoa sheet with rounded corners like the image below?

### Xcode 4 Rounded Sheet

[image: Xcode 4 Sheet - Rounded Corners]

I've looked all over but I cannot seem to find anything on it. I'm not sure if I'm looking in the wrong places, or if this just isn't a common practice. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the NSPanel reference?

Comment: @CodaFi This doesn't have anything to do with `NSPanel`.

Comment: Added sample code to my answer - just wanted to let you know (leaving a comment will pop up a notification - just editing my answer won't).

Comment: @Itai Ferber thank you very much! Everything works perfectly!

Comment: Excellent, glad to have helped!

Comment: Updated my answer again with some new information. Thought you might want to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:** it turns out that this behavior is even easier if you're targeting OS X Lion or later - simply calling `[sheet setOpaque:NO]` is enough to enable rounded corners.

---

This behavior is pretty easy to reproduce. Initialize your sheet to be a transparent borderless window:

```
self.sheet = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 300) styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered | NSTitledWindowMask defer:YES];
[self.sheet setOpaque:NO];
[self.sheet setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```

Add as a subview a custom view:

```
[[self.sheet contentView] addSubview:[[IFWindowView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self.sheet contentView] frame]]];
```

That custom view should do its drawing as follows:

```
#define RADIUS 5.0
NSBezierPath *bezierPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:NSMakeRect(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y + RADIUS, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height) xRadius:RADIUS yRadius:RADIUS];
[[NSColor windowBackgroundColor] set]; // In production, use the appropriate color with alpha for transparency.
[bezierPath fill];
```

Here is some sample code to demonstrate this in action: http://d.pr/l9DB

Comment: NOTE: For NSAlerts you can also use the above edit. `[alert window] setOpaque:NO]` Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell, this is a property of the window.  If it is a panel, it has square corners, if a window, round corners.  At least that's what happens under Mac OS - can't vouch for iOS.